# Unorderable types int and string

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this, I can enter the name fine but when I go to enter the height, I get an unorderable type error.

```
floatHeight = 0
floatWeight = 0
strName = ""

strName = input("What is your name? ")



while floatHeight <= 1 or floatHeight >= 3:
    floatHeight = input("What is your height in metres? ")
while floatWeight <= 10 or floatWeight >= 400:
    floatWeight = input("What os your weight in kilograms? ")
print(floatWeight)
print(floatHeight)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the inputted values into `float`:

```
while floatHeight <= 1 or floatHeight >= 3:
    floatHeight = float(input("What is your height in metres? "))
while floatWeight <= 10 or floatWeight >= 400:
    floatWeight = float(input("What os your weight in kilograms? "))
```

Otherwise `floatHeight` or `floatWeight` will be a string. Fortunately, in Python 3 and you cannot compare strings and floats anymore.